# Consider all types in external dll as nullable with C# Nullable reference types

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I use C# Nullable reference types in my project and I have reference to some other dll that does not support Nullable reference types.

Can I somehow tell compiler that all properties in external dll can be null? By default compiler show all as not null.

Comment: The external dll must be nullable annotated for that. Do you have control over it and access to sources?

Comment: No, I have no control over external dll

Comment: As workaround, you can control [nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) in places, where external dll is used, by disabling nullable warnings/context and restoring it back, like `#nullable disable` /`#nullable disable warnings` and restore them using `#nullable restore`. The rest of the your code will still use all benefits of new feature

Comment: Relevant github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/42318) and [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2244)

Answer (score 1):

Values from unannotated code are treated as 'oblivious', meaning their nullability is unknown. Analysis for such values behaves in the same way as before the NRT feature existed.

You should not need to disable the nullable context for code that consumes that library. You just wont gain any insight into where nulls may flow into your code, and where nulls may be incorrectly passed to that external code.

Ideally you would obtain an annotated version of the assembly. If it has a small enough surface area, you could provide your own an annotated shim.

Comment: Does that only sound weird to me? If I am in a nullable-enabled context, and consume a result from a library that was built in a nullable-disabled context then I would expect like @Mikel that I get a warning when I try to assign an 'oblivious' value (one that has no annotations) to a non-nullable declared variable, as oblivious means "it might be null" which should be treated as "is nullable" imho (with maybe a different warning number so it can specifically be enabled/disabled). Or are we now totally off the track?

Comment: In practice getting a warning for assigning an oblivious value to a non-oblivious value would produce so much noise for most people that the feature would be turned off. It's my belief that the right trade off was made here, having now migrated several codebases to using nullable annotations.

Comment: It would cost you 1 minute to shut the warning off in your project if it is too noisy, but for us how wants them - we don't have a chance to put them on now. It's simply not intended (or at least I didn't find a way yet except the attribute-waving-in-solution which I don't feel comfortable with to apply on 3rd-party assemblies).

Comment: As an experiment you could recompile an unannotated project with nullable enabled and all warnings suppressed, then try consuming it from a nullable context with warnings. You could also author a Roslyn analyser to warn about usages of oblivious types that concern you.

Comment: Does not work as all reference types are e.g. `String` and not `String?` in an unannotated project. And yes, I would love to write such an analyzer but I guess my customer does not pay me for that...