# Benefits of C# 8.0 nullable reference types when working with external libraries

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm currently in the process of updating an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project to .NET 5 and at the same time trying to take advantage of some of the newer C# language features such as: [C# 8.0's nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

I tried enabling it for one of my projects and started going through some of the warnings popping up. At one place I'm zipping a folder where I have some debug logging:

```
var dirInfo = _fs.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName(absPath);
var subEntries = dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos();
foreach (var info in subEntries)
{
    var isDirInfo = IsDirectory(info.Attributes);
    _logger.Debug("Adding item to archive with parameters: type={type}, name={name}, bytes={size}",
        isDirInfo ? "directory" : "file",
        info.Name,
        isDirInfo ? 0 : (info as FileInfoBase).Length);
    //                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.

    AddToZip(archive, info.FullName, Path.Join(entryPath, info.Name), isDirInfo);
}
```

In the above snippet `_fs` is an `IFileSystem` from the [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) library. The exact warning above has nothing to do with the actual question here but my investigation into how to properly fix it made me wonder why a warning is not shown at the second line of the snippet. There's nothing in the `FromDirectoryName` signature that says it cannot be null, since the library is not using this feature yet. So, I'd expect the compiler to assume `dirInfo` may be null and show a warning when trying to dereference it at the second line. (Let's for a moment pretend that `FromDirectoryName` would return null rather than throw an exception if `absPath` does not exist - it's my best real world example at the moment)

As far as I've been able to find out around the internet this is expected. In other words: because the return type of `FromDirectoryName` is `IDirectoryInfo` and not `IDirectoryInfo?` the compiler behaves as if `dirInfo` will never be null. Whether this is a design choice or technical limitation I don't know, but it made me wonder what the benefits of this new nullable reference type are. To me it seems like not being able to rely on the compiler to warn you about your use of values returned from external libraries defeats quite a big part of this "new" feature because it may lead you to overlook potential null-reference exceptions.

Am I either interpreting the compiler's behavior in above code snippet incorrectly or am I just having the wrong approach to using nullable reference types in a project that depends on several external libraries? I hope you can help enlightening me a bit on how to approach the use of this language feature in such situations.

---

**Edit (13-01-2021):**

In a [blog post from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/#what-happens-when-you-call-libraries-that-have-not-enabled-the-feature) they even point out that you cannot trust the compiler to interpret method signatures from libraries that haven't enabled the feature yet. It strengthens my theory that unless you are working on a project with very few 3rd party libraries, you are likely to waste your time implementing this feature and still not get null-safe code.

**Edit (14-01-2021):**

Added a reproducible example: https://github.com/Xerillio/csharp8-nrt-test

Comment: Not very sure what you are concerned about - if a method tells you it is not going to return null (via returning `T` and not `T?`) why do you think you still need to add the null check?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem is, that a library that has not enabled nullable reference types has no notion of a `T?`. Hence all consumers of the library will only see `T` as the return type, even though the method does in fact return null in some cases. But the compiler will not warn you about this (unless I misunderstand)

Comment: Nullable reference types were only ever intended to help write safer code. That is to say: you will get more warnings than you previously did about possibly unsafe situations (previously, you got 0). The demand for a feature that lets you write code that is *provably safe* is often stated, but if this had been a design goal from the start, NRTs would likely never have gotten off the ground in the first place, as the hill to climb from existing code is just too high. It is a common misconception that this makes NRTs useless -- it does not, but it does mean you must temper expectations.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I completely get your point, although I don't believe it's useless. It does, however, require a lot of discipline to use I believe, because the described issue (I also added a repro) has a high chance of giving you a false sense of safety. Perhaps I'm overexaggerating the issue but I'm wondering why there's no option treat return/parameter types from "legacy" libraries as nullable by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consider all types in external dll as nullable with C# Nullable reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316599/consider-all-types-in-external-dll-as-nullable-with-c-sharp-nullable-reference-t)